# In a JRPG Battle system. Who executes the selected action?

Tags: unity, c#, rpg

Throughout the JRPG history, we've seen the introduction of many a battle system type. Like the classic turn-based. The ATB. The action battle system  (Most Notable is Kingdom Hearts)

In these systems, there's a variety of skill handlers like a queue or gauge to determine turn. My question put simply is who handles the executing of skills? Is it the Battle system? The Players? The Skill queue if there is one?

Right now I'm working on an ATB styled Final Fantasy in Unity. I'm leaning towards either the player or the battle system executing the commands. I have my players with each a separate state machine (WAIT, COMMAND, ACTION) And a command queue that holds the queued up actions. I can either have the player in the ACTION state and the battle system process the logic(Execute whatever queued up action). Or the player handle that.

Outside of that. I'm curious how it works for the other types of battle systems since I hope others in the future with a similar question can see this.

Comment: Any of the above. What makes the most sense for your implementation, or the code conventions that you follow in your team/project? Did you run into any specific difficulty implementing one of the approaches that you list?

Comment: Not particularly. I'm leaning more towards the battle system executing actions in my system personally. I'm more just curious as to when one or the other makes sense if truly they all can be and were used in different games

Comment: It sounds like you have what you need to make forward progress then. Try implementing it the way you're leaning toward. If you find you run into a problem that way, edit your question to demonstrate that specific problem. You'll generally get much more high-quality, focused, actionable answers when you present a concrete problem to solve.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm still curious though as I'm still trying to decide/test each idea in my system I just have a leaning not a concrete answer yet.

Comment: "Curiosity' usually isn't enough to make a high-quality StackExchange question. We can't really evaluate which one has benefits for your game, because we haven't seen your game, its specific needs, or the existing implementation you're building on. So in its present form, this question is likely to attract opinions and hearsay, rather than testable, demonstrable improvements for your project.

Comment: Right I'll edit my question then

Comment: I still don't see a specific problem that you've run into when putting this on either the player, or the battle system. Try whichever one seems OK to you, and if you encounter a problem, please post here to explain the problem in detail.